# Reporting against a CSV field in a SQL server 2005 DB

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, csv, parsing

Ok so I am writing a report against a third party database which is in sql server 2005.  For the most part its normalized except for one field in one table. They have a table of users (which includes groups.)  This table has a UserID field (PK), a IsGroup field (bit) , a members field (text)  this members field has a comma separated list of all the members of this group or (if not a group) a comma separated list of the groups this member belongs to.

The question is what is the best way to write a stored procedure that displays what users are in what groups?  I have a function that parses out the ids into a table.  So the best way I could come up with was to create a cursor that cycles through each group and parse out the userid, write them to a temp table (with the group id) and then select out from the temp table?

UserTable
Example:
ID|IsGroup|Name|Members
1|True|Admin|3
2|True|Power|3,4
 
3|False|Bob|1,3
4|False|Susan|2
5|True|Normal|6
6|False|Bill|5

I want my query to show:
GroupID|UserID
1|3
2|3
2|4
5|6

Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have (or could create) a separate table containing the groups you could join it with the users table and match them with the charindex function with comma padding of your data on both sides.  I would test the performance of this method with some fairly extreme workloads before deploying.  However, it does have the advantage of being self-contained and simple.  Note that changing the example to use a cross-join with a where clause produces the exact same execution plan as this one.

**Example with data:**
`SELECT *

FROM   (SELECT 1       AS ID,

               '1,2,3' AS MEMBERS

        UNION

        SELECT 2,

               '2'

        UNION

        SELECT 3,

               '3,1'

        UNION

        SELECT 4,

               '2,1') USERS

       LEFT JOIN (SELECT '1' AS MEMBER

                  UNION

                  SELECT '2'

                  UNION

                  SELECT '3'

                  UNION

                  SELECT '4') GROUPS

         ON CHARINDEX(',' + GROUPS.MEMBER + ',',',' + USERS.MEMBERS + ',') > 0`

**Results:**

```
id  members group
1   1,2,3   1
1   1,2,3   2
1   1,2,3   3
2   2       2
3   3,1     1
3   3,1     3
4   2,1     1
4   2,1     2
```

Comment: Preliminary testing with this method looks good.  I don't really care about performace since this query will be run a couple of times a quarter with less about a dozen groups and (maybe) twice that in users. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your technique will probably be the best method.

Comment: Based on the fact that SQL Server doesn't parse text data very well.  The only way to parse through a text field of an unknown length is via a loop or cursor.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks for you help.